# Why Swap is used when plenty of free memory is left?

Tags: linux, mysql, php

I have pretty good web (dedicated) server with good memory resources:

```
System information
Server load     2.19 (8 CPUs)   
Memory Used     29.53% (4,804,144 of 16,267,652)    
Swap Used   10.52% (220,612 of 2,097,136)
```

As you can see, my server is using swap when there is plenty of free memory available.

**Is this normal or is there something wrong with the configuration or the coding ?**

N.B.
My MySQL process is using over 160% of the CPU power for some reason; I don't know why, but I don't have more than 70 simultaneous users ...

Comment: Applications can use over 100% of the CPU in Linux? Erm...

Comment: @BlueRaja: Yes, because in Linux CPU utilization is measured relative to a single CPU, not all the CPUs in your system.  So in a machine with 8 CPUs, you have a maximum of 800% CPU available.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA  version 5.5

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

At system startup, a number of services start. These services initialize themselves, read in configuration files, create data structures and so on. They use some memory. Many of these services will never run again for the entire time the system is up because you're not using them. Some of them may run in hours, days, or weeks. Yet all this data is in physical memory.

Of course, the system can't throw this data away. It can't prove that it will literally never be accessed. One of those services, for example, might be the one that provides you remote access to the box. You may not have used it in a week, but if you do use it, it had better work.

But the system knows that it might like to use that physical memory for things like a disk cache or in other ways that will improve performance. So it does opportunistic swapping. When it has nothing better to do, it writes data that hasn't been used in a very long time to disk, using swap space. However, it still keeps the pages in physical memory. So they can still be accessed without having to swap them in.

Now, if the system later needs that physical memory for something else, it can simply throw those pages away because it has already written them to swap. This gives the system the best of both worlds. The data is still kept in memory, so it can be accessed without having to read it from disk. But if the system needs that memory for another purpose, it won't have to write it out first. Big win all around.

Comment: In that case can you please explain why sometimes swap space is not at all used.

Mem:  49554484k total,  4087592k used, 45466892k free,349244k buffers



Swap:  94204k total,   0k used, 94204k free, 1113644k cached

Comment: @ananthan: There could be many reasons. The most likely is that the system never was under any memory pressure at all, even due to buffered writes, so the opportunistic swap code may never have been triggered. It could also be that someone thought any swap usage was bad and so mis-tuned the system not to swap opportunistically (by reducing *swappiness*).

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if at some time in the past you needed more memory than you have physical RAM in the machine. At that time some data will have been written to the swap space.

When later memory gets freed, data from swap is not automatically read back into RAM: this only happens when the data in swap is actually needed by some process. This is perfectly normal.

As for your mysql process: this all depends on the type of queries you run. In theory 2 very complex queries could probably suffice to get such a load, regardless of your number of users. You could enable the slow query log to gain more insight into which queries are load-intensive.

Comment: No - swap usage is not a high water mark. When swapped out pages are mapped back the disk pages are marked as not in use (but may still contain data).

Comment: I only mentioned one scenario in which you can have swap usage, but this indeed is not always symptomatic of having not enough physical memory - as also explained by David Schwartz above

Answer (score 4):

You can also change this behaviour by `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`, which will greatly reduce the use of swap until it is actually needed.

As for MySQL, have you at least performed a baseline configuration test using the [tuning-primer.sh](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/tuning-primer.sh) script?

Comment: This will increase the tendency for cache/buffers to be reclaimed. Unfortuinately it's not clear from the original question whether the figure of 29.53% includes buffers/cache - if it does not, then making the change you suggeast will have an adverse impact on performance. If this dbms is using innodb extensively then it's probably been badly configured (although a single 8 core 16gb box for use as a webserver is a BAD deisgn choice to begin with)

Comment: why you say its bad choice for web server ? i dont use innodb much i still prefer myisam because my reads are 70% and writes only 30%....

Answer (score 1):

This is probably, as David explained, a normal behavior of the Linux Kernel, but it can also be an occurrence of the [MySQL “swap insanity” problem](http://blog.jcole.us/2010/09/28/mysql-swap-insanity-and-the-numa-architecture/).  In your case (8 CPU, 16 GB RAM total, 5 GB used), for that to happen, your computer should be a NUMA system with 4 nodes (sockets) and 4 GB of RAM per node and a MySQL InnoDB buffer pool of 4 GB.

In short (you should read the link above for complete details), this is what happen:

1. When your system start, processes are spread on all the NUMA nodes using some of their memory.
2. When MySQL starts, it allocates 4 GB for the InnoDB buffer pool, filling the RAM of a NUMA node and using some RAM on other nodes.
3. Then, the Linux kernel, which cannot move allocated RAM from one NUMA node to another, thinks it is  good idea to swap out pages from the starved node (or need to swap out pages because pages needed to be swapped in).

To avoid that, change the memory allocation for MySQL to allocate RAM on all cores (see the above link for more details).