# High load cause?

Tags: linux, memory, central-processing-unit, io, high-load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is my server high load cause (4 cores and 8 thread cpu)](https://serverfault.com/questions/461990/what-is-my-server-high-load-cause-4-cores-and-8-thread-cpu)

What is my high load cause?
CPU,RAM or IO?
4 Core, 8 thread cpu

```
top - 22:27:07 up 149 days,  5:26,  1 user,  load average: 17.43, 13.34, 9.65
Tasks: 1018 total,   1 running, 1016 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 36.6%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 59.5%id,  2.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.4%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16413676k total, 16076104k used,   337572k free,    95772k buffers
Swap: 10190840k total,    77100k used, 10113740k free,  2030160k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2776 mysql     15   0 10.8g 9.8g 5496 S 230.8 62.8  55189:04 mysqld
  656 apache    15   0  370m  18m 5248 S  4.0  0.1   0:00.65 httpd
24611 apache    15   0  401m  50m 6824 S  2.3  0.3   0:02.92 httpd
25744 apache    15   0  371m  20m 6144 S  2.3  0.1   0:01.53 httpd
20970 apache    15   0  371m  21m 6552 S  2.0  0.1   0:02.94 httpd
27381 apache    16   0  370m  19m 5808 S  2.0  0.1   0:00.96 httpd
30195 apache    15   0  370m  20m 6452 S  2.0  0.1   0:00.81 httpd
30569 apache    15   0  371m  20m 5920 S  2.0  0.1   0:01.18 httpd
20411 apache    15   0  370m  20m 6532 S  1.7  0.1   0:03.11 httpd
24971 apache    15   0  371m  19m 6064 S  1.7  0.1   0:02.83 httpd
  612 apache    15   0  370m  19m 5504 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.45 httpd
  870 apache    15   0  371m  19m 5372 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.35 httpd
 1071 apache    15   0  370m  19m 5212 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.26 httpd
 1083 apache    15   0  371m  19m 5148 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.22 httpd
22456 named     21   0  475m 4724 1984 S  1.3  0.0  30:06.94 named
24905 apache    16   0  371m  20m 6092 S  1.3  0.1   0:01.96 httpd
30060 apache    15   0  371m  20m 6192 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.79 httpd
30231 apache    15   0     0    0    0 Z  1.3  0.0   0:00.78 httpd 
30548 apache    15   0  370m  19m 5524 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.87 httpd
  511 apache    15   0  370m  18m 4928 S  1.0  0.1   0:00.14 httpd
  548 apache    16   0  370m  19m 6032 S  1.0  0.1   0:00.57 httpd
  914 apache    15   0  370m  19m 5524 S  1.0  0.1   0:00.29 httpd
 1078 apache    15   0  371m  19m 5416 S  1.0  0.1   0:00.47 httpd
 1441 apache    15   0  371m  19m 5116 S  1.0  0.1   0:00.10 httpd
```

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  3  77156 170328  92928 1994240    0    0    94   272    0    0 15  1 79  5  0

iostat
Linux 2.6.18-274.12.1.el5        01/22/2013

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.17    0.22    0.97    5.08    0.00   78.56

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             125.35      1506.84      4344.95 19428091086 56020516230
sda1              0.00         0.03         0.00     435588        230
sda2            125.35      1506.81      4344.95 19427652146 56020516000
dm-0            566.23      1504.90      4343.25 19403104530 55998658464
dm-1              0.45         1.90         1.70   24547232   21857536

```
Total DISK READ: 92.74 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 2.77 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 5475 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 % 99.99 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
  801 be/3 root        0.00 B/s 1012.68 K/s  0.00 % 99.99 % [kjournald]
  511 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 71.27 % httpd
 5281 be/4 apache     22.26 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 31.33 % httpd
23269 be/4 apache      3.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 17.86 % httpd
24937 be/4 apache     33.39 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 12.45 % httpd
26167 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s -26.42 %  9.83 % httpd
22460 be/4 named       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.65 % named -u named
 2776 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.56 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
 5494 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 99.99 %  0.56 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
22461 be/4 named       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.09 %  0.46 % named -u named
30222 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.46 % httpd
 5496 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s -2.15 %  0.37 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
 1227 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.37 % sh /usr/local/ddos/ddos.sh
 5507 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.37 %  0.28 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
22464 be/4 named       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % named -u named
22465 be/4 named       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % named -u named
    5 rt/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % [migration/1]
   23 rt/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % [migration/7]
 4191 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % httpd
 4321 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % httpd
24857 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % sleep 3000
30204 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % httpd
24532 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.28 % httpd
 4267 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s -0.28 %  0.28 % httpd
 5516 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.28 %  0.19 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
 5515 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.19 % mysqld --base~sql/mysql.sock
24926 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.19 % httpd
 4250 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.19 % httpd
  871 be/4 apache      0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.19 % httpd
```

```
free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16413676   16116940     296736          0     120612    2411292
-/+ buffers/cache:   13585036    2828640
Swap:     10190840      77448   10113392
```